# Can't figure out how to add padding to left side of Ubuntu 20.04.5 CLI in WSL 2(On Win11)

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, ubuntu-20.04

*Posting here with updated detail after posting on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443807/cant-figure-out-how-to-add-padding-to-left-side-of-terminal-in-wsl-2-ubuntu-20) as user @NotTheDr01ds had a great answer but unfortunately it did not accomplish what I was hoping to accomplish.*

I installed WSL 2 and Ubuntu following directions from a class I'm taking and am setting up my terminal to be how I like it, set up my `.bashrc`'s PS1 to my liking. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to add padding to the window as there is 1px between the edge of my monitor and the first char and it is visually distracting.
[image: Ubuntu terminal launched from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS]

All the research I've done says this is the solution:

- Add the following code to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
     VteTerminal,
     TerminalScreen,
     vte-terminal {
         padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     }
```

However, I don't have `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and when I create it it doesn't do anything. I have a `Z:\etc\gtk-3.0` which has two files; im-multipress.conf and settings, settings containing:

```
[Settings]
  gtk-theme-name = Yaru
  gtk-icon-theme-name = Yaru
  gtk-sound-theme-name = Yaru
  gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu-bar=24,24
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-appearance#padding shows that it is possible and that it should be accessible from a `settings.json` file, which I was able to find through the windows Terminal, however this only seems to affect my Ubuntu CLI when launched through the `Terminal`, **my goal is to have this padding when launched from `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`**:
[image: Ubuntu terminal launched from Terminal]

I am lost because the way the class had me set it up my working directory is `Z:\home\jake_windows_11\` all the resources I've found are working with Windows terminal in their root. For reference my `.bashrc` file is in `"Z:\home\jake_windows_11\"` if that helps. (I've been told on Ask Ubuntu its not ideal and not POSIX compliant and problems occur but that's how my class instructed us to set it up so it must stay this way.)
[image: My working directory for my class]

I'm sure I left out important information so don't hesitate to probe for more information which I can update my post with, I've spent way to long on this already but I know it has to be possible so I'll keep trying till I find an answer that works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm - So you set Windows Terminal to be the default as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install#set-your-default-terminal-application) and it still launches into the *old* terminal when running Ubuntu application?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds AHHH, I missed the step 'set "Windows Terminal" as the Default terminal application setting'! Thank you again for your help, I apologies for my poor direction handling.

Comment: Again (over here), no worries.  I do recommend deleting this one when you get a chance since it is essentially a cross-post of the (now fully answered) one of Ask Ubuntu.  Glad to hear you got it resolved, even if it did take postings on 3 different sites ;-).